# Armstrong Numbers Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am new to java programming ,please tell me what is wrong with this implementation of the Armstrong's Number Algorithm.

It's printing "1" infinite times.

An Armstrong number of three digits is an integer such that the sum of the cubes of its digits is equal to the number itself. For example, 371 is an Armstrong number since 3**3 + 7**3 + 1**3 = 371.

Reference: https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html

Code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter range:");

        int num =s.nextInt();
        int range = s.nextInt();
        int rem,temp;
        int sum;

        System.out.println(num+" "+range);

        while(num<=range) {
             sum=0;
            temp=num;
            while(temp>0) {
                rem=temp%10;
                sum=sum+(rem*rem*rem);
                temp=temp/10;
            }
            if(sum==num)
                System.out.println(sum);

            num++;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: when will num ever become > range? what is the point of range? you are never using it in your logic?

Comment: Debug your application.

Comment: If you’re new to Java, write the code in a language you’re familiar with. Then learn Java syntax to migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = num / 10;
```

You are reassigning your counter variable.

Let the variable num be 1, and range be 10.

When we get to `num = num / 10;`, you are setting num to 0. Thus, num will always be less than range (which is 10) causing your program to fall into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(num>0) {
        rem=num%10;
        sum=sum+(rem*rem*rem);
        num=num/10;
    }//By the wnd of this loop num always will be euqals to zero.
        if(sum==temp)
            System.out.println(sum);

        num++;//So here always num value will be 1.So it never cross the range value.
    }
```

So try following code:

```
while(num<=range) {
         sum=0;
        temp=num;

        while(temp>0) {
            rem=temp%10;
            sum=sum+(rem*rem*rem);
            temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(sum==num)
            System.out.println(sum);

        num++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

write the code in a language you know it well Then learn Java syntax to migrate so it will be easy to change it to java

Comment: This suggestion isn't intended to answer the question and might be more suitable as a comment.